# How can I test my API from random locations globally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I am building an API in AWS, and it works great since I'm using regional API Gateway. I'm also using location based Route 53.

What I'd like to do is to pretend that I'm in us-east for example (currently I'm in eu-west). I tried using VPN, but result is the same as without VPN. So, I'd like to test latency of this API from random places in the world, or places of interest. Any ideas how can that be achieved?

Thanks,

Marko